# Python - Getting an error when trying to start an executable with Pywinauto (Steam in this case)

Tags: python, ocr, steam, pywinauto

I am trying to automate the installation of Steam using Pywinauto, as part of a larger automation project that involves multiple applications. However, I am getting the following error: `pywinauto.application.AppStartError`. I have checked the file path and it seems correct. Additionally, I have tried running the script with administrator privileges, but the error still occurs.
Could anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and find a solution? Thank you.

```
import os
import urllib.request
import subprocess
import pywinauto
import pytesseract
import time
from pywinauto.timings import WaitUntilPasses
from PIL import ImageGrab


def download_steam():

    # Define the official download URLs for Steam
    # steam_url = 'https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe'
    steam_url = 'https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe'

    # Define the destination directory for the downloaded file
    download_folder = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')

    # Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
        os.makedirs(download_folder)
    print(f"Destination folder: {download_folder}")

    # Define the file name for the Steam download
    steam_filename = os.path.join(download_folder, 'SteamSetup.exe')
    print(f"Steam file name: {steam_filename}")

    # Download the Steam file
    print("Downloading Steam...")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(steam_url, steam_filename)

    # Wait for the Steam installer to download
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Steam downloaded successfully.")

    # Run the Steam installer & wait for the installer window to appear
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Starting Steam installation...")
    pywinauto_backend = 'uia'
    app = pywinauto.Application(backend=pywinauto_backend)
    try:
        app = pywinauto.Application(backend=pywinauto_backend)
        app.start('SteamSetup.exe')
        dlg = app.window(title='Steam Setup', class_name='#32770')
        print("Steam installer window found.")
    except pywinauto.application.AppStartError:
        print("Error starting Steam installer. Make sure the SteamSetup.exe file is in the downloads folder.")
        return

    # Click "Next" until reaching the additional software installation screen
    dlg['Next'].click()
    while dlg.wait('visible', timeout=5, best_match='.*Steam - Install.*', found_index=0):
        dlg['Next'].click()

        # If an offer to install additional software appears, click "No"
        additional_software_title = '.*Install Additional Software.*'
        if dlg.wait('visible', timeout=5, best_match=additional_software_title, found_index=1):
            # Use OCR to check if the software is actually Steam-related
            bbox = dlg.rectangle()
            screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot).lower()
            if 'steam' in text:
                dlg['Yes'].click()
            else:
                dlg['No'].click()

    # Click "Finish" to complete the installation
    dlg_finish = dlg['Finish']
    dlg_finish.click()

    # Wait for the installation to complete
    installer_title = 'Steam'
    installer = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(
        60, 1, lambda: pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(title=installer_title)
    )
    print("Steam installation completed successfully.")`
```

I have been debugging step by step and it seems that the error comes from this section, more specifically in the step "app.start('SteamSetup.exe')". But there might be something else.

@Vasily Ryabov

```py
python .\main.py
Destination folder: C:\Users\user\Downloads

Steam file name: C:\Users\user\Downloads\SteamSetup.exe

Downloading Steam...

Steam file downloaded successfully.

Starting Steam installation...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1038, in start
    (h_process, _, dw_process_id, _) = win32process.CreateProcess(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Script\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    download_steam() # Download Steam
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Script\steam.py", line 46, in download_steam
    app.start('SteamSetup.exe')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "SteamSetup.exe"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: I want to clarify that I'm new to automation and I have been using the help of ChatGPT :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post the error message from `AppStartError`? I mean `str(exc)` for `except AppStartError as exc:` handler. Also do you have spaces in `download_folder` path?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov replied you after "the code" at post

Answer (score 0):

Obviously folder path `C:\Users\user\Downloads` is not present in environment variable PATH. You can check it in Python by getting `os.environ["PATH"]`. If you add it there, everything should work. Or just use the full path to executable in method `.start(...)`

It is also easy to check in `cmd.exe` console:

```
echo %PATH%
SteamSetup.exe /?
```

Option `/?` may be helpful for checking silent installation options. Almost each installer has such option (like `/s`). Typically it's enough using silent run by `subprocess.check_output("SteamSetup.exe /s")` or something like this. GUI automation is necessary if you're QA engineer working at Steam. :)